# Discretization of matrix differential equation $\dot{Q} = \frac{1}{2}\Omega Q + \frac{1}{2}Q\Omega^T$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

We know that $\dot{x}(t) = Ax(t)$ can be [discretized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discretization) as follows

$$x[k+1] = A_d x[k]$$ where $$A_d = e^{AT}$$

where $T$ is the sample time.

If I have the following differential equation, how do I obtain its discretized form? (and how to find its $A_d$)

$$\dot{Q} = \frac{1}{2}\Omega Q + \frac{1}{2}Q\Omega^T$$
where   $Q$ is **symmetric and positive semidefinite** matrix and $\Omega$ is **skew symmetric** matrix.

I think  I can obtain the following:
$$\dot{Q} = \frac{1}{2}\Omega Q - \frac{1}{2}Q\Omega$$

Then I have no idea how to discretize this in the form similar to the one in Wiki?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Vectorizing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_(mathematics)) the given matrix differential equation, we obtain the following differential equation

$$\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d t} \mbox{vec} (\mathrm Q) =  \frac 12 \left( \mathrm I \otimes \mathrm \Omega + \mathrm \Omega \otimes \mathrm I \right) \mbox{vec} (\mathrm Q)$$

If $\mathrm Q$ must be symmetric, then the above is wasteful, as we only need the entries on and above (or below) the main diagonal. In that case, we can use half-vectorization and [duplication matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duplication_and_elimination_matrices).

Comment: So you mean that if $Q$ symmetric, then $\operatorname{vec}(Q)$ can be replaced by $D_n \operatorname{vech}(A) = \operatorname{vec}(A)$ in the link "duplication matrices" you provide?

Comment: Yes, exactly...

Answer (score 1):

You can easily confirm that 
$$
Q(t)=\left(e^{\frac t2Ω}\right)Q_0\left(e^{\frac t2Ω}\right)^T
$$
satisfies this differential equation. In general you will get problems with ODE with matrix-valued coefficients for matrix valued solutions as the usual methods for constant real coefficients strongly rely on the commutativity of the real numbers.

Comment: This answer looks nice. However, what do you mean "rely on the commutativity of the real numbers"?  How could you use this to give that answer "intuitively"?   Sorry I just take undergraduate fundamental course for differential equation.